# Do I have to make an Arcane roll to concentrate if I take less damage than my Toughness?

Tags: savage-worlds, hellfrost

Let's say my character has Toughness 6 and is maintaining one spell. The character takes 7 points of damage, so I have to make an arcane roll to maintain said spell with a difficulty of 7. But what if the damage had been 6 or less?

**Q: Do I have to make an arcane roll if I take less damage than my toughness to concentrate?**

One of my players said that if an enemy doesn't beat your toughness you get no damage (His argument was that the armor soaks the damage).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was clarified several times on the official forums, for example [here](http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=24409), as the wording of the rules in the core book is unclear.

In that post, Clint Black, the official rules guru for Savage Worlds, confirms that you must be at least Shaken to have to roll to maintain your spells:

> He doesn't have to make any roll because the damage doesn't exceed his Toughness. The description may not be entirely clear, but in essence it works like this...If the caster suffers a Shaken result from damage or takes 1 or more wounds, they must make an Arcane Skill roll against the total damage or his maintained spells are disrupted.

Comment: This forum post is from 2003, my rulebook is from 2011. How in hell did this not make it into it? Is there a published book with the correction? You should not have to dig up archived forums for a rules reference.

Comment: As it turns out, [Clint Black](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/37248/clint-black) has an account on this site. Perhaps he could weigh in on this (or post his own answer)?